# Unable to create PHP-MySQL connection in Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: mysql, php

The application was working fine prior to update of 21.10
After going through the details I found there is issue with php-mysql connection in 21.10.

I am using the same code since ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: There is not enough information here to do anything with. You will need to check your error logs in `/var/log/apache2` to see what the issue might be, then act accordingly. One thing to note is that 21.10 uses PHP 8 by default, whereas 18.x and 20.x have used PHP 7.

Comment: Find the log that shows what error you get. 1 thing that probably did change: 18.04 used MySQL 5. 21.04/21.10 USES MySQL8.